# Overload both &self and &mut self method

Tags: rust, constants, overloading, const-correctness

Rust, unlike C++, does not have function overloading. Consider a linked list model that, in C++, would look like:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class Node {
private:
    T value;
    std::unique_ptr<Node<T>> next;

public:
    Node<T>& getNext();
    const Node<T>& getNext() const;
};
```

When you deal with a constant list, you cannot modify it because you can only have access to `const Node<T>&`, at the same time you can modify a non constant list.

What is the equivalent of this behaviour in Rust? Consider a more complex example with multiple methods. Only some of them must be overloaded with both `&mut self` and `&self`.

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn getNext(&self) -> Option<&Self> {}
    pub fn getNext(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Self> {}
}
```

Comment: Idiomatic Rust uses `snake_case`, not `camelCase`.

Comment: also C++ is snake_case, just for information completeness (and types are lower case).

Comment: [gnzlbg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42514762/3650362) on the other question solves your problem directly. But I'd recommend against it. The ability to dispatch methods on the const-ness of the reference was one of my first big WTF moments learning C++

Comment: @barsan-md That's incorrect. There is no single style guideline for `C++`.